# Using Join, select values from multiple SQL tables without a foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join

I have a database containing two tables `Team` and `User`.
Every team can have one or two users in it.
I wish to select an output of the table `Team` such that information of the both the users from the table `User` are included.
It'll be easier to understand once I define the table structures.

Table `Team`:

```
+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| team_name |     user_one      |     user_two      |    team_note    |
+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| Team one  | skuhsa@jdds.dfd   | kgihse@kdhf.dfj   | one to twenty   |
| Team two  | dsjgknsz@djfd.fkg |                   | three to thirty |
+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

Table `User`:

```
+-------------------+-----------+-----------------+
|       email       | user_name |    user_note    |
+-------------------+-----------+-----------------+
| skuhsa@jdds.dfd   | skuhsaone |   gimme money   |
| kgihse@kdhf.dfj   | kgihse    |    drop it      |
| dsjgknsz@djfd.fkg | dsjgknsz  |   just eat it   |
+-------------------+-----------+-----------------+
```

The output I'm looking for goes like this.

```
+-----------+--------------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+-----------------+
| team_name | user_one           | user_name | user_two         | user_name | team_note       |
+-----------+--------------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+-----------------+
| Team one  | skuhsa@jdds.dfd    | skuhsaone | kgihse@kdhf.dfj  | kgihse    | one to twenty   |
+-----------+--------------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+-----------------+
| Team two  | dsjgknsz@djfd.fkg  | dsjgknsz  |                  |           | three to thirty |
+-----------+--------------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+-----------------+
```

I have a good feeling that it can be done easily, but right now I'm trying all sorts of JOINs and stuff and ending up with duplicate results or rows.
If there is any PostgreSQL specific ways to do it, it'd just fine with me.

`SELECT * FROM Team LEFT JOIN User ON Team.user_one=User.email` works, but how do I select only the columns I want? i.e., how will it differentiate b/w columns for the first and the second user?

Comment: if you have 10 users you`ll get a really long table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of `left join`s should do the trick:

```
SELECT    team_name, user_one, u1.user_name, user_two, u2.user_name, team_note
FROM      team t
LEFT JOIN user u1 ON t.user_one = u1.email
LEFT JOIN user u2 ON t.user_one = u2.email
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually quite simple, as the comment says simply use a `LEFT join`, this could by saying `LEFT JOIN [TableName]`

```
SELECT * FROM [Team] 
LEFT JOIN [User]
```

Also take a look at

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Edit:

Your second option would be to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM [Team]
UNION
SELECT * FROM [User]
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?
an exact query with the `ON` part is what I'm looking for!

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code you tried to run?

Comment: That depends on which row you want the 'ON' to be, you could go : 
SELECT * FROM [Team] 
LEFT JOIN [User] 
ON [Team].[user_one]=[User].[email]

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
    LINE 1: SELECT * FROM [Team]

Comment: Try : SELECT * FROM Team LEFT JOIN User ON Team.user_one=User.email

Comment: Okay. That works. But how do I only select the columns I want?
ie how do i differentiate b/w the columns for first user and the second user?

Comment: You can do this by using the SELECT statement, for example, SELECT Team.User_one, User.Email

Answer (score 0):

An [inner join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) or a [left join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) can be used to extract data from both tables.

But the result of the query will be more similar to the following:

```
+-----------+--------------------+-----------+-----------------+
| team_name | user_one           | user_name | team_note       |
+-----------+--------------------+-----------+-----------------+
| Team one  | skuhsa@jdds.dfd    | skuhsa    | one to twenty   |
+-----------+--------------------+-----------+-----------------+
| Team one  | skuhsa@jdds.dfd    | kgihse    | one to twenty   |
+-----------+--------------------+-----------+-----------------+
| Team two  | dsjgknsz@djfd.fkg  | dsjgknsz  | three to thirty |
+-----------+--------------------+-----------+-----------------+
```

This is the best solution because you don't know how many users are present in a team what happens if they are 3 (or 100?) ? But it is different from your expectations so check if you agree with that form.

Comment: @Mureinik gave a solution which gives me exactly what I wanted, mate.

Comment: Yes but it works only with a number user between 0 and 2. If your team has a maximum of two user is ok, but in this case instead of a relationship 1 n is better to provide a relationship 1 2 adfing two foreign key with unique index nullable in the team pointing the user.

Comment: Oh I just understood what you said. Yes, this is just for some data analysis. I'm so glad it has max 2 users per team! I'm definitely going to include a foreign key to the `Team` table in the `User` table next.

Answer (score 0):

firstly you sould re-think aout tables. What is the meaning wirting user e-mails in two different tables? In the end you will get all of them in one table.

Other than that you shoul look at `foreign key`. Foreign keys link tables together. I think your tables must be like.

```
+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+-
| team_name |    team_note      |     team_id(Primary key)
+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+
| Team one  | one to twenty     |       1
| Team two  |     stuff         |       2
+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+


+-------------------+-----------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------
|       email       | user_name |    user_note    |  f_team_id(foreign_key) to team.team_id
+-------------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------------------------------
| skuhsa@jdds.dfd   | skuhsaone |   gimme money   |       1
| kgihse@kdhf.dfj   | kgihse    |    drop it      |       1
| dsjgknsz@djfd.fkg | dsjgknsz  |   just eat it   |       2
+-------------------+-----------+-----------------+------------------------------------------
```

After that

```
SELECT * FROM team JOIN user ON user.f_team_id=team.team_id; OR
SELECT * FROM team, user WHERE user.f_team_id=team.team_id;
```

Comment: I used a simple database for explaining the issue I'm facing mate.
What I actually have is a huge django portal with two models which were hastily designed to just work. I have no way of adding a foreign key now without messing up the whole shebang! I do have teamid and userid in the tables, but no teamid in the User table!
But yes, this is exactly how it should have been! :)